# Short exact sequence of tensors

Tags: tensor-products, exact-sequence

Consider the following sequence
[image]

Where $\gamma: n \mapsto 2n $ and $\varphi: n \mapsto \overline{n}$. When using the properties of tensors we get the sequence of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which is clearly not exact. On the other hand, $\text{im}(\gamma\otimes1) = \{2k \otimes l \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}, l \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \} = \{0\otimes 0 \}$ and $\ker(\varphi\otimes 1) = \{k\otimes l \mid \varphi(k) = \overline{0} \text{ or } l = \overline{0} \} = \{0\otimes 0\}$. Therefore, $\text{im}(\gamma\otimes1) = \ker(\varphi\otimes 1)$, which gives us that the sequence is exact.  Is my image or kernel wrong?

Comment: Why do you say "which is clearly not exact"? If you "reduce" to a sequence of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$s, then the $\gamma\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}1$ "reduces" to the 0 map and the $\varphi\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}1$ map "reduces" to the identity map.

Comment: Sequence $0 \rightarrow  \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow  \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow  \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$ is not exact, as the homorphisms are not zeros, hence kernel does not equal to image

Comment: Oh you're looking at the left position. In the middle, it's exact as noted in the answer from @Eric Wofsey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence is indeed exact in the middle (though your method of checking this really requires more justification--in general, not every element of a tensor product $A\otimes B$ has the form $a\otimes b$, and moreover $a\otimes b$ can be $0$ even if neither $a$ nor $b$ is $0$).  The place it fails to be exact is on the left: $$0\to\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{\gamma\otimes1}{\to}\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$$ is not exact because the kernel of $\gamma\otimes 1$ is nontrivial.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks.

Comment: What will be the kernel and image in this case?